# Animatedsprite at godot 3.1

Tags: sprites, godot

In Scene Player, I changed the sprite to animated sprite and created two modes, stand and walk, and wrote these scripts to move the player. But when I play the scene, the characters don't show their animations.
I don't know what is problem.

```
func _physic_ptocess(delta):  
  if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    acceleration_player.x = player_speed
    $Sprite.play("walk")
    $Sprite.flip_h = false


  if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    acceleration_player.x = -player_speed
    $Sprite.play("walk")
    $Sprite.flip_h = true


  if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
    acceleration_player.y = -player_speed
    $Sprite.play("walk")


  if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
    acceleration_player.y = player_speed
    $Sprite.play("walk")


  else:
    $Sprite.play("stand")
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
    acceleration_player.y = player_speed
    $Sprite.play("walk")


else:
    $Sprite.play("stand")
```

I want you to focus on the `else` branch:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
    # ...
else:
    $Sprite.play("stand")
```

It says that if you are not pressing the action `"ui_down"` the animation will be `"stand"`. In which case the rest of calls to `play` do not matter.

*I suppose a solution is to make most of these `if` into `elif`. But then you won't be able to combine vertical and horizontal input. Instead...*

---

I want to encourage to separation of concerns. Let us separate the visuals which is what you care about:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    acceleration_player.x = player_speed

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    acceleration_player.x = -player_speed

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
    acceleration_player.y = -player_speed

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
    acceleration_player.y = player_speed

# visuals

if abs(acceleration_player.x) < 0.00001 and abs(acceleration_player.y) < 0.00001:
    $Sprite.play("stand")
else:
    $Sprite.play("walk")
    if acceleration_player.x < 0:
        $Sprite.flip_h = true
    else:
        $Sprite.flip_h = false
```

Note: the reason I check `abs(acceleration_player.x) < 0.00001` instead of `acceleration_player.x == 0.0` is just in case the value does not hit `0.0` exactly due to floating point errors, which I don't know if they are possible or not in your code. *I would have used `is_zero_approx` in Godot 3.2 or newer.*

I submit to your consideration to leave only the check for `acceleration_player.x` in the conditional. In particular if `"walk"` does not represent an appropriate animation for vertical motion.

By the way the second part can be more compact if you want:

```
    $Sprite.flip_h = acceleration_player.x < 0
```

Comment: Thank you
Only when I write this code.... ( if is_zero_approx(acceleration_player.x) and is_zero_approx(acceleration_player.y):
    $Sprite.play("stand")  ) it gives this error for this part:  " method 'is_zero_approx' is not declared in the current class"and does not allow me to play the scene.
(Godot 3.1)

Comment: Even when the player has no speed, it moves very slowly and never shows a standing position.
Even and never stop.

Comment: @NinaMonti I had forgotten that `is_zero_approx` wasn't available in Godot 3.1, that is why I changed it to `abs(...) < 0.00001` so use that. You might want to tweak the threshold if it is never standing. How do you decelerate is beyond this question.

Comment: Thanks.I see and edited my codes.